# Какой алгоритм регрессии выбрать для шумных (разбросанных) данных?

Tags: машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

Я хочу построить регрессию с несколькими переменными (multiple features). В моих данных у меня `n = 23` переменных и `m = 13000` тренировочных примеров. Вот график моих тренировочных данных (площадь квартиры vs цена):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь на графике отображены 13000 тренировочных данных. Как вы можете видеть, это достаточно шумные данные. Мой вопрос: какой алгоритм регрессии больше подходит и обоснован для использования в моем случае. Имею ввиду логично ли использовать простую линейную регрессию или лучше использовать какой-либо нелинейный алгоритм регрессии.

Для наглядности приведу примеры.
Вот отвлеченный пример линейной регрессии:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А также отвлеченный пример нелинейной регрессии:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот примеры с гипотетическими линиями регрессии для моих данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понимаю, примитивная линейная регрессия для моих данных произведет большую суммарную погрешность (error cost), так как эти данные шумные и разбросанные. С другой стороны, здесь также не прослеживается какой-либо отчетливой нелинейной зависимости (например синусоидальной). Какой алгоритм регрессии более рационально использовать в моем случае (цены на квартиры) для того чтобы получить более точное прогнозирование цен. И почему этот алгоритм (линейный или нелинейный) более рационален?

**Дополнение:**
Вот так выглядит мой график линейной зависимости цены от всех 23 параметров:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю, как бы выглядела НЕлинейная зависимость в таком случае. И была бы она более рациональна чем линейная.

Comment: у вас слишком мало параметров используется, в данном случае даже увеличение числа экспериментов не даст никакого результата. Добавьте еще параметры (на вскидку - наличие ремонта, удаленность от центра, район и т.д.) и тогда прогнозирование будет более адекватным

Comment: Как я написал в вопросе у меня 23 параметра. В вопросе я их назвал "переменными". В их числе и перечисленные Вами варианты параметров. На данный момент цена у меня линейно зависит от всех 23 параметров. И я думаю что было бы логичнее использовать линейную или какую-либо нелинейную регрессию.

Comment: вчера как раз было начало [одного из курсов на coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/), где-то в курсе рассматривается аналогичный пример с ценой на квартиры и описано что и как надо сделать, чтобы получить более-менее адекватную модель

Comment: если у вас уже 23 параметра, то почему тогда вы используете из них только два? добавляйте больше параметров

Comment: Я добавил график линейной зависимости цены от 23 параметров, отображенный на данных цена-площадь.

Comment: вы по графику пытаетесь определить адекватность, но уже для 3 параметров график должен быть 3-хмерным, а не 2-х, для 23 параметров - вообще по графику ничего сказать нельзя. Смотрите на ваш error-cost, если уменьшается, значит ваша модель приближается к данным. Только уменьшая ошибку вы рискуете получить неадекватную модель, которая будет только копировать ваши входные данные. На другом реальном наборе ошибка может быть больше грубой оценки. Если тема интересна - посмотрите лекции, там теории достаточно по теме (правда, практика там сильно хромает, мне только из-за этого курс не понравился)

Comment: _"площадь квартиры vs цена"_ см. http://habrahabr.ru/post/148782/

Comment: @Stack, автор в статье упоминает все тот же курс, о котором я писал выше ) А все потому, что там как раз на этом примере идет объяснение как такие данные надо анализировать

Comment: Cross-posted on Stats.SE, Stack Overflow, SO.RU, and DataScience.SE: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188291/2921, http://stackoverflow.com/q/34474767/781723, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486133, http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/9529/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для сравнения статистических моделей обычно используют информационные критерии, например, [информационный критерий Акаике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5). Если вы пишете на R, то посмотрите функцию `stepAIC` - она позволяет упростить линейную модель, выкидывая из нее предикторы по одному, в порядке возрастания значимости для модели.